# A way to display an excel 2010 document in an asp.net web application

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, excel-2010

I am wanting to display an Excel 2010 document in an asp.net web application. This document uses the new slicer functionality which I want to be available to the user.

I know that Excel 2010 docs can be used within SharePoint by inserting a web part which uses Excel services.

But can it be achieved without SharePoint ? Or can it be achieved using the the Excel services API to get the document from SharePoint and then somehow get it to the browser in .net?

Thanks,
Tom.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the Slicer functionality but.... Excel cells are available via a REST interface within SharePoint 2010 (not 2007). That may help you get to the data you want to expose.

More information on the Excel and Rest with SharePoint 2010 [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20101020061934/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/excel/archive/2009/11/05/excel-services-in-sharepoint-2010-rest-api-syntax.aspx).

From a non SharePoint perspective, the [Skydrive](https://skydrive.live.com/) based Web Office apps have Excel functionality. It is possible you may be able to impersonate a user, send a HTTP request to try and bring back the Excel data for display. You could possibly use an IFrame for display also. Having said that, I have never tried it and not sure how well it would work.

Comment: Hi.

I thought about iframing both the web office app and sharepoint, but this seems like a workaround.

The data can't be stored externally so counts the office app out.

I can't use any of the API's because they only allow access to the data. I want to display the whole spreadsheet and let it be interactive to the user. Just like you can on the web office or through sharepoints web part.

Any other suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: If you are able to look at SP 2010, here is information about using Excel Services, which could then tie into ASP.NET

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms546696.aspx

Alternately, you could possibly consider some third party web controls to see if they support the functionality you require. http://www.componentsource.com/features/spreadsheet/asp-net-controls/index.html

Comment: Thanks John. I have looked into custom controls but I think using SP be my only real solution for this one. Thanks again.